# How to distribute the square of the sum of two radicals?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

|  |
| --- |
| $ (\sqrt{2x+1} + \sqrt{3x+5})^2 $ |
| $ (\sqrt{2x+1} + \sqrt{3x+5})(\sqrt{2x+1} + \sqrt{3x+5}) $ |
| $ (\sqrt{2x+1})(\sqrt{2x+1} + \sqrt{3x+5}) + (\sqrt{3x+5})(\sqrt{2x+1} + \sqrt{3x+5}) $ |
| $ \sqrt{(2x+1)(2x+1)} + \sqrt{(2x+1)(3x+5)} + \sqrt{(3x+5)(2x+1)} + \sqrt{(3x+5)(3x+5)} $ |

If you graph the first 3 expressions, you will see that the graph result is the same. However, as soon as you graph the last expression, you realize that you are working with a different graph result.

What is going on here? The distributive property seems to be right.

Comment: What changes about the graph? Is it just the domain and range?

Comment: It changes the entire trajectory of the graph. As if you were dealing with a different problem. Graph it and you will see.

Comment: Actually, it is the domain that changes.

Comment: @CyclotomicField Why are changes occurring, the distributive property is not supposed to change anything.

Comment: @YGranja It's not distributivity, it's when you combine the square roots. Note that the values under the square roots can't be negative and so when you change it that can change the domain.

Comment: $\sqrt x \cdot \sqrt{x}$ has a different domain than $\sqrt{ x^2}$

Comment: @Vasili it's the $\sqrt{2x+1} \sqrt{3x+5} = \sqrt{(2x+1)(3x+5)}$ step that causes problems not the square terms.

Comment: @CyclotomicField: Certainly, I just wanted to show that we should take domain into account when combining roots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The domains are different.

In order to evaluate the expression $(\sqrt{2x + 1} + \sqrt{3x + 5})^2$, we require that $2x + 1 \geq 0 \implies x \geq -1/2$ and that $3x + 5 \geq 0 \implies x \geq -5/3$.  For both statements to be true, $x \geq -1/2$.  Hence, the domain is $[-1/2, \infty)$.

In order to evaluate the expression $\sqrt{(2x + 1)^2} + 2\sqrt{(2x + 1)(3x + 5)} + \sqrt{(3x + 5)^2}$, we require that $(2x + 1)^2 \geq 0 \implies x \in \mathbb{R}$, that $(2x + 1)(3x + 5) \geq 0 \implies x \leq -5/3$ or $x \geq -1/2$, and that $(3x + 5)^2 \geq 0 \implies x \in \mathbb{R}$.  In order for all three statements to be true, $x \leq -5/3$ or $x \geq -1/2$.  Hence, the domain is $(-\infty, -5/3] \cup [-1/2, \infty)$.

Consequently, the graph of $y = (\sqrt{2x + 1} + \sqrt{3x + 5})^2$ has a single branch, while the graph of $y = \sqrt{(2x + 1)^2} + 2\sqrt{(2x + 1)(3x + 5)} + \sqrt{(3x + 5)^2}$ has two branches.